# how do you create a select with both value and the label the same from an array in cakephp?

Tags: html, cakephp-1.3

I created an array in the controller from a table :

```
$tasktemplateResults = $this->Tasktemplate->find('list');
```

And in the view I have a form helper that creates a drop down list:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Tasktemplate.id', array('options' => array($tasktemplateResults),'label' => 'Task'));
```

The html output is as follows:

```
<div class="input select">
    <label for="TasktemplateId">Task</label>
    <select name="data[Tasktemplate][id]" id="TasktemplateId"> 
        <option value="1">Test task</option> 
        <option value="2">Second test task</option> 
    </select>
</div>
```

I would like to have this html output:

```
<div class="input select">
    <label for="TasktemplateId">Task</label>
    <select name="data[Tasktemplate][id]" id="TasktemplateId"> 
        <option value="Test task">Test task</option> 
        <option value="Second test task">Second test task</option> 
    </select>
</div>
```

How do I get the name and value pairs the same as the array as shown above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add parameters to the find 'list' method to specify which fields to use for the key and the value.

Example:

```
    $usernameMap = $this->Article->User->
find('list', array('fields' => array('User.username', 'User.first_name')));
```

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1022/find-list

Comment: I did look that up very carefully before posting this question, the reason this does not work is due to the fact that I use `'options' => array($tasktemplateResults)` which is dynamically populated based on on a table.

Comment: Your options array is populated by the find.  Therefore, if you adjust your find query as I noted, it should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting as the book didn't explain this clearly with multiple fields and list.

Comment: Does not work for me. My select options are still <option value="1">Text 1</option><option value="2">Text 2</option><option value="3">Text 3</option>

Answer (score 1):

array in the controller

```
$tasktemplateResults = $this->Tasktemplate->find('list', array('fields' => array('Tasktemplate.name')));
```

and in view

```
echo $this->Form->select('task', $tasktemplateResults);
```