# How do you create a form select making value the same as option text from db array

Tags: php, html, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Let's say I have in my controller:

```
$this->set('locations', $this->Location->find('list', array('fields' => array('state')) ));
```

**How do I get my view to generate a form select with options:**

```
<select name="data[Location][state]" class="inputbox" id="Location">
<option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
<option value="California">California</option>
<option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
</select>
```

Because it is generating:

```
<select name="data[Location][state]" class="inputbox" id="Location">
    <option value="1">Arizona</option>
    <option value="2">California</option>
    <option value="3">Hawaii</option>
    </select>
```

I'm aware that cakephp uses primary key by default for the values and there's an answered question but the solution did not work for me:
[how do you create a select with both value and the label the same from an array in cakephp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531112/how-do-you-create-a-select-with-both-value-and-the-label-the-same-from-an-array)

In my view, I have:

```
<?php echo $form->select('Location.state', $locations); ?>
```

My database is: `locations`
**id | state**
1 | Arizona
2 | California
3 | Hawaii
and so on

Answer (score 0):

alright, solution was pretty simple...in my controller the fields array needed the value and text specified:

```
$this->set('locations', $this->Location->find('list', array('fields' => array('state','state')) ));
```

Answer (score 0):

> When calling list you can configure the fields used for the key and value with the keyField and valueField options respectively:
>
> http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs

```
$locations = $this->Location->find('list', ['keyField' => 'state', 'valueField' => 'state']);

$this->set('locations', $locations);
```

Comment: he's using cake 1.3

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->set('locations', $this->Location->find('list', array('fields' => array('state','state')) ));
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!